# handler.postDelayed unit test not running

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

i need to coverage this snnipet of code and the tests units not covering. A principle I need my test to cover this "handler.postDelayed()" instruction and also check whether this "handler.postDelayed" was actually called with Mockito/Junit.

**CropSettingViewHandler.java**

```
   if(dataHandler.isCropSettingsFirstAccess()) {
           handler.postDelayed(() -> {
              cropSettingsView.getCropTypeInfoButton().performClick();
           }, 100);
           dataHandler.setCropSettingsFirstAccess(false);
        }
     }
```

**CropSettingViewHandlerTest.java**

```
    @Test
    public void testCropSettingsFirstAccess() {
        InfoButton mockInfoButton = mock(InfoButton.class);
        when(mockCropSettingsView.getCropTypeInfoButton()).thenReturn(mockInfoButton);
        when(mockCropSettingsView.getCropSettingsCategoryButton()).thenReturn(mockCategoryButtons);

        ArgumentCaptor<CategoryButtons.CategoryButtonsEventListener> categoryButtonEventListerCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(CategoryButtons.CategoryButtonsEventListener.class);
        verify(mockCategoryButtons, times(1)).setCategoryButtonsEventListener(categoryButtonEventListerCaptor.capture());
        CategoryButtons.CategoryButtonsEventListener catergoryButtonEventListener = categoryButtonEventListerCaptor.getValue();

        when(mockDataHandler.isCropSettingsFirstAccess()).thenReturn(false);
        catergoryButtonEventListener.onCategoryButtonsAfterExpand(mockCategoryButtons);
        verify(mockInfoButton, never()).performClick();

        when(mockDataHandler.isCropSettingsFirstAccess()).thenReturn(true);
        catergoryButtonEventListener.onCategoryButtonsAfterExpand(mockCategoryButtons);
        Awaitility.await().pollDelay(101, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).until(() -> true);
        verify(mockInfoButton, times(0)).performClick();

        ShadowLooper.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks();
    }
```

Reading some comments and documentation on the internet I saw about this instruction: ShadowLooper.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks();

But it is specific to the UI and not the handler.postDelayed() that I need to cover, is there any other way to cover my handler other than the UI?